# Trying to understand flow of a program

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

i am trying to do a push notification app .  i have been following Ravi Tamada's blog for this http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/  i did not understand the flow of one of the classes..

the classes is as follows..

```
 public class InitialActivity extends Activity {
// label to display gcm messages
TextView lblMessage;

// Asyntask
AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> mRegisterTask;

// Alert dialog manager
AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

// Connection detector
ConnectionDetector cd;

public static String name;
public static String email;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_pn);

    cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

    // Check if Internet present
    if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
        // Internet Connection is not present
        alert.showAlertDialog(InitialActivity.this,
                "Internet Connection Error",
                "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
        // stop executing code by return
        return;
    }

    // Getting name, email from intent
    Intent i = getIntent();

    name = i.getStringExtra("name");
    email = i.getStringExtra("email");      

    // Make sure the device has the proper dependencies.
    GCMRegistrar.checkDevice(this);

    // Make sure the manifest was properly set - comment out this line
    // while developing the app, then uncomment it when it's ready.
    GCMRegistrar.checkManifest(this);

    lblMessage = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblMessage);

    registerReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver, new IntentFilter(
            DISPLAY_MESSAGE_ACTION));

    // Get GCM registration id
    final String regId = GCMRegistrar.getRegistrationId(this);

    // Check if regid already presents
    if (regId.equals("")) {
        // Registration is not present, register now with GCM   
        lblMessage.append("inside first if condition where regid = null" + "\n\n"); 
        GCMRegistrar.register(this, SENDER_ID);
    } else {
        // Device is already registered on GCM
        if (GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this)) {
            // Skips registration.              
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Already registered with GCM", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            // Try to register again, but not in the UI thread.
            // It's also necessary to cancel the thread onDestroy(),
            // hence the use of AsyncTask instead of a raw thread.
            lblMessage.append("inside 2nd if condition where regid != null and GCMRegistrar.isRegisteredOnServer(this) = false " + "\n");   
            final Context context = this;
            mRegisterTask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    // Register on our server
                    // On server creates a new user
                    lblMessage.append("inside doinbackground" + "\n\n");
                    ServerUtilities.register(context, name, email, regId);
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
                    mRegisterTask = null;
                }

            };
            mRegisterTask.execute(null, null, null);
        }
    }
}       

/**
 * Receiving push messages
 * */
private final BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        lblMessage.append("inside BroadcastReceiver mHandleMessageReceiver " + "\n\n"); 
        String newMessage = intent.getExtras().getString(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        // Waking up mobile if it is sleeping
        WakeLocker.acquire(getApplicationContext());

        /**
         * Take appropriate action on this message
         * depending upon your app requirement
         * For now i am just displaying it on the screen
         * */

        // Showing received message
        lblMessage.append(newMessage + "\n\n");         
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "New Message: " + newMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        // From Demo Server: successfully added device!
        // Releasing wake lock
        WakeLocker.release();
    }
};

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (mRegisterTask != null) {
        mRegisterTask.cancel(true);
    }
    try {
        lblMessage.append("onDestroy " + "\n"); 
        unregisterReceiver(mHandleMessageReceiver);
        GCMRegistrar.onDestroy(this);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("UnRegister Receiver Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}

now its output is as follows.. 
[image]

the program enters broadcast receiver 3 times.. how does this happen? i applied the same code to another app but the code entered broadcast receiver only once..  so what is going on??

Comment: You could ask Ravi Tamada, whoever he is

Comment: @Alex i did.. no response.. and i kinda need this urgently..

Comment: I would suggest that instead of using this blog (which is not very recent), you use the current official demo For GCM. You can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/gcm/source/browse/gcm-client/GcmClient/src/main/).

Answer (score 0):

The comments says it all. Looking at the code in the beginning, you'll check for the internet connection. Second once it is checked, you are going to register the receiver for receiving GCM messages. First you'll try to get the registration ID from GCM server for your device. If not registered(for which you'll get "") then try to register your device in GCM server which is important for getting GCM messages. Once registered for that app project(for which you won't get any ids) then try to register in the your server because your server need to have unique registered ID of your mobile to send GCM messages. Receiver is to receive the messages that comes from GCM. This is what the whole code says. For Step by step code, sorry. You need to atleast put some effort for that.

Comment: ok i agree.. but what i dont understand is the receiver is always listening.. thus even if the code is provided in a different app it should be working?? ryt??

Comment: If the receiver has to respond for all broadcast then all the application would have responded for all broadcast(Like whatsapp alert for Facebook friend request. :P. Just joking). I guess you have to read go through the documentation of GCM more thoroughly.

Comment: <!-- Creates a custom permission so only this app can receive its messages. -->
    <permission
        android:name="com.androidhive.pushnotifications.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />. This code will make your application to respond to particular message that your GCM sends. That is of your application.

Comment: So as the other app developers has their own custom permissions so that there application will respond to particular message, i,e of there app.